# Permissions aren't being loaded for Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions

Just started my first chrome extension and I'm trying to use the chrome.bookmarks.getChildren() method. I am getting an error saying

> Uncaught Error: You do not have permission to use 'bookmarks.getChildren'. Be sure to declare in your manifest what permissions you need.

My manifest.json file:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Top Sites",
"description": "blah blah blah",
"version": "1.0",
"permissions": [
    "bookmarks"
],    
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
}
```

}

Comment: What is the name and location of your permissions file?

Comment: its just manifest.json file in the root of my application.